# Figure fail to load at the same body content after button submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I can't find ths solution to my problem. Maybe because I am generating WebFigure from MATLAB. Hope someone could save me. And obviously I am new to this thing and not really sure how to do it.

I have successfully use jquery to load the other page (multipledose.jsp) in the same body content from index.jsp. In this other page, there is some calculation, which after the button submit, the graph (webfigure MATLAB) will appear in the same location without updating the whole page. . But after many trials, the graph keeps on going to a different page. Below are the codes that I think that may have resulted to the problems:

**multipledose.jsp**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" media=all href="./StyleSheet.css" />

<%
String tfinalStr = request.getParameter("tfinal");
int tfinal = 100;
if (tfinalStr != null && tfinalStr.length() > 0) {
    tfinal = Integer.parseInt(tfinalStr);
}

String yiniStr = request.getParameter("yini");
String yini = "10 0 0 0";
if (yiniStr != null && yiniStr.length() > 0) {
    yini = yiniStr;
}

%>

</head>

<body>
<center>
    <!--
   <form action="http://localhost:8080/MultiDose">
-->
    <form action="MultiDose">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td>Time<br> <input type="text" name="tfinal"
                        id="tfinal" value="<%=tfinal%>" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td>Initial Condition<br> <input type="text" name="yini"
                        id="yini" value="<%=yini%>" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="10"><input type="submit"
                        value="Display Graph" name="DoPLot" id="DoPLot" onclick="$('#body').show();" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
        <br> <br>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="PKdiagram1.gif" alt="PK Diagram" width="500"
                    height="250"></td>
                    <div id="body">
                        <wf:web-figure root="WebFigures" name="Project_Figure"
                            scope="session" />
                    </div>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</center>
</body>
```

**MultiDose.java**

```
result = pkModel.RunPKmodelMultipledoseVI(1, param);
WebFigure webFig = (WebFigure) ((MWJavaObjectRef) result[0]).get();

request.getSession().setAttribute("Project_Figure", webFig);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/multipledose.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Really hope someone could help. Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I have updated the code as suggested by adding `RequestDispatcher` in MultiDose.java and changing the `<jsp:include>` in multipledose.jsp to a direct call of `<wf:web-figure>`. However, the submit button, which should only update the content `body` containing the `webfigure` is not working and displaying a new full multipledose.jsp page.

Comment: maybe you want something like `RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("somePage.jsp");
  rd.include(request, response);` Write this statement towards the end of servlet.

Comment: Hi @Nivedita. I used that before. using multipledose.jsp but it will move to the multipledose.jsp page and not only loading the graph. I guess, something need to be done with this code..Any idea?

Comment: `the graph keeps on going to a different page. ` what is the url you get when the graph is shown ?

Comment: You're not using Ajax, so why wouldn't it go to a different page?

Comment: @Nivedita. I have updated the above codes based on your suggestion. The URL that I get after the submit button is http://localhost:8080/CombineDoseProject/MultiDose?tfinal=100&yini=10+0+0+0&DoPLot=Display+Graph.

Comment: Hi @developerwjk. I am really new to this web development and don't know anything about Ajax. I am referring to other websites and forums to build until this stage. But I am stuck with the latest problem. I just need the graph to be updated without going to a new page. Any advice?

Comment: When you do a submit it always goes to a new page, or reloads the same page. Ajax is the way to get around that.

Comment: The page will be reloaded when using RequestDispatcher as suggested by developerwjk. Is it happening or you are getting errors? If you don't want the page to reload, you will have to use Ajax. If this is what you want

Comment: Using the RequestDispatcher is okay. No error. But it will move to a different page, while I need it to just update the related content at the same page. @developerwjk is right. After looking at the Ajax information, I think this is what I need to use. I am looking at it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From your last comment ,

> But it will move to a different page, while I need it to just update the related content at the same page

you can even use `RequestDispatcher` to forward to the same page from which you are posting the data .

And you can print the data in the page using `El` as ,

```
${Project_Figure}
```

but it is always better to use ajax, if you are reloading a part of a page.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Hi @SanKrish, thanks for your help. I have looked into the problem and I definitely have to learn using ajax for this. After few days of trying, I am still stuck with it. Need to take more time in learning the structure.

Comment: you are welcome :) ajax has many resources hope you could learn it easily